# How do I write to a CSV file using the apache log4j2 functionality and the log4j2 configuration file?

Tags: java, csv, logging, log4j

I have been trying hard to generate a CSV file using CsvParameterLayout in Log4j. I have coded the log4j2 configuration file as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
<Properties>
<Property name="csvLog.fileName">C:/ql/logs/csvLog</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
<RollingFile name="csvFile" fileName="${csvLog.fileName}.tmp"
    filePattern="${csvLog.filename}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.csv" header="${file-header}">
        <CsvParameterLayout delimeter=","/>
        <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"
                    modulate="true" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="200" />
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
<Root level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="csvFile" level="debug"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

However, I am not able to generate the required CSV file. Could anyone please help me on this? Also in the future, I want to add a unique ID before everything I am printing which I will generate using thread context.

Please help.

Comment: Please explain which part is not working. Is the file not created, has it completely wrong content, is something missing from it ...

Comment: The delimiter spelling is wrong..but correcting it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: The file is not created.

Comment: OK, have you created log files before with log4j?

Comment: actually our application does create log files...although I haven't worked on it myself..ive been assigned this as a POC..so in short my application does create log files (Ive just attached a snippet for confidentiality) but I havent worked on this module.

Comment: Is it that I need the commons-csv.jar?

Comment: I dont know. I would hope that this is documented somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the Log4j 2 documentation of the [CSV Layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html) it depends on [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

Find below working snippets.

pom.xml

```
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="csvLog.fileName">csvLog</Property>
        <Property name="file-header">column1,column2,column3</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="csvFile" 
                     fileName="${csvLog.fileName}.tmp"
                     filePattern="${csvLog.filename}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.csv" >
            <CsvParameterLayout delimiter="," header="${file-header}\n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="200" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="csvFile" level="debug"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Java snippet

```
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(...);
logger.info("sample output", "foo", "bar");
```

output `csvLog.tmp`

```
column1,column2,column3
foo,bar
```

**edit**

log4j2.properties

```
appenders = csvFile

appender.csvFile.type = RollingFile
appender.csvFile.name = CSVFILE
appender.csvFile.fileName = csvLog.tmp
appender.csvFile.filePattern= csvLog-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.csv
appender.csvFile.layout.type = CsvParameterLayout
appender.csvFile.layout.delimiter = ,
appender.csvFile.layout.header = column1,column2,column3\n
appender.csvFile.policies.type = Policies
appender.csvFile.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.csvFile.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.csvFile.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.csvFile.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.csvFile.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.csvFile.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.csvFile.strategy.max = 200

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = csvFile
rootLogger.appenderRef.csvFile.ref = CSVFILE
```

Comment: This seems just what I was looking for. I have to download the commons CSV jar. Thank you so much Sub Optimal! I will mark this answer correct as soon as I test it tomorrow.

Comment: By the way, it seems the first entry in the log -> "sample output" didn't make it to the file. Any reason why this is so?

Comment: @SiddharthMehta If you would have had a look at the link I posted [CSV Layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html) you would have seen it mentioned `The CsvParameterLayout converts an event's parameters into a CSV record, ignoring the message.` (the message is ignored, alternatively you can log using an `ObjectArrayMessage`)

Comment: could you write configuration in property style?

Comment: I have this config  `code`log4j.appender.activity=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.activity.file=../logs/activity.log
log4j.appender.activity.append=true
log4j.appender.activity.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.activity.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout
log4j.appender.activity.threshold=info`code`
what set to layout when i want csvlayout?

Comment: @SultanZhumatayev I added an example `log4j2.properties` (for Log4j 2). The CSV layout does not exist for Log4j 1.x.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation here:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/CsvParameterLayout.html

logging for CSV Layout should be via `ObjectArrayMessage`

`logger.debug(new ObjectArrayMessage(1, 2, "Bob"));`

Answer (score 0):

Version for groupID: "org.apache.logging.log4j" should be 2.7 else it will include some extra characters while writing the logs to CSV.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```